# Wordpress Gravity PDF CSS column

Tags: html, css, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I am trying to style my WordPress Gravity form PDF but I cannot seem to get rid of the white space between the 2 columns. There isn't really a way to inspect elements on the PDF so it's not easy to change the CSS for it.

I've tried outputting the actual HTML to see what elements are in there. But putting things like:

```
margin:0;
padding:0;
border:0;
```

on those elements doesn't do anything.

I also found this article from Gravity PDF itself that shows how to work with the column classes and I just tried putting CSS on those as well (No result)

[Gravity PDF Article](https://gravitypdf.com/documentation/v5/user-css-ready-classes/)

```
.gfpdf-field,
.gf_first_quarter,
.gf_second_quarter,
.gf_third_quarter,
.gf_fourth_quarter,
.gf_left_half,
.gf_right_half,
.gf_left_third,
.gf_middle_third,
.gf_right_third,
.gf_list_2col,
.gf_list_3col,
.gf_list_4col,
.gf_list_5col {
   padding: 0 !important;
   margin: 0 !important;
   border: 0 !important;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know the underlying css, have you tried zero for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-gap (column-gap) or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap (grid-gap)

Comment: @CarolMcKa looked promising, but none of these options change anything. Could be because I am putting it on the wrong element or because it isn't the problem. (Not really sure how to figure that one out)

Comment: are you sure its `margin` and `padding` and not the `width`? could they are giving `width` something like `48%`. try with changing `width` to `50%` for half column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure its `margin` and `padding` and not the width? Could they are giving width something like `48%`. Try with changing width to `50%` for half column.

Comment: That's it! I changed my columns to 50% and removed the padding and it worked. Thanks!